# Увеличение лимита в WCF сервисе

Tags: c#, wcf

пытаюсь передать в wcf сервис `byte[]` превышающий 64кб, для этого в конфиге прописал

```
<netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IService" 
             transferMode="Buffered"
             maxBufferPoolSize="20971520" 
             maxBufferSize="20971520" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="20971520">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="20971520"
                    maxStringContentLength="20971520"
                    maxArrayLength="20971520"
                    maxBytesPerRead="20971520"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="20971520" />
      <security>
        <transport sslProtocols="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
```

и на стороне клиента и на стороне сервера, но все так же вылетает

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: "Превышена квота максимального размера сообщения для удаленного канала. Подробнее см. в журналах сервера."
```

пытался выловить это в лог и посмотреть подтягивает ли оно вообще из конфиг файлв эти ограничения, но судя по тому что он никак не отреагировал на `<system.diagnostics>`в конфиге, мне кажется он плевать хотел на конфиг, при этом на "левые" атрибуты ругается из кода как на не правильные

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в `<endpoint>` на стороне сервера следует прописать `bindingConfiguration="myBind"` к нужному биндингу

```
<binding name="NetTcpBinding_IService" 
             transferMode="Buffered"
             maxBufferPoolSize="20971520" 
             maxBufferSize="20971520" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="20971520"/>
<services>
      <service name="name">
        <endpoint bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IService" 
              address="you address" 
              binding="netTcpBinding" contract="you contract"/>
      </service>
</services>
```